# Custom Window property in global.d.ts does not exist

Tags: typescript, global, tsconfig

I am trying to have window object contain a custom object and have added this into global.d.ts

global.d.ts:

```
import type { JsonObject } from 'src/shared/utils/json';

declare global {

  interface Window {
    dataLayer: JsonObject[];
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
...
"include": ["*.d.ts"],
...
```

This seems to be picked up as configured in tsconfig.json:

```
$ tsc --p tsconfig.json --listFiles | grep global
C:/Users/eruina/<repo-name>/node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts
C:/Users/eruina/<repo-name>/node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.global.d.ts
C:/Users/eruina/<repo-name>/global.d.ts
```

But when accessing window.dataLayer in other *.ts files, a following error is shown:

```
TS2339: Property 'dataLayer' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

Asides using *.d.ts filename pattern and adding the global file into tsconfig.json, are there any other steps I'm missing?